# System boots directly into windows without BIOS option

Tags: boot, bios, windows-11

I just assembled a new PC with the following config:

- Gigabyte B760M AORUS ELITE AX DDR4
- i5 13500
- Windows 11 Pro

When my system boots, it goes directly to the windows login page. As per the motherboard manual, I kept pressing DEL when PC starts but it doesn't work. Moreover, I don't see the motherboard manufacturer logo which usually comes when system starts.

Would appreciate any help/info on this. Thanks.

**Update**: Seems it has something to do with the graphic card/display output option. I've got an NVidia GPU so my display was connected to the GPU. However, when I plug my display cable to the onboard DP port, BIOS entry works. This has left me as confused.

**Update 2**: There was a BIOS update but that didn't help.

**Update 3**: This is getting more and more interesting/confusing. So, despite plugging the display to the integrated DP port, my discrete GPU also works at the same time. My game works (but HDR disabled for some reason) and Davinci Resolve also detects/works with the Nvidia GPU. This is so confusing for me because I've come straight from 3rd gen i5 where you had to use either integrated or discrete GPU, not both. Also, CSM is disabled in BIOS.

Comment: Get the machine going, and then restart (slows down Fast Startup).  See if you now see a screen that says Press  "Key" to enter BIOS. This may work.

Comment: That's the thing, windows login is the first screen that appears

Comment: Maybe turn OFF Fast Startup (Windows Power screens, needs to be Admin), restart and try again.

Comment: @Peregrino69 i've mentioned that in my post.

Comment: @John i've updated my post, please check if you have any idea.

Comment: Sorry you're right. I need new glasses :-P Removing inappropriate comment.

Comment: That must be something to do with your BIOS and PC build. Not a normal way to get into BIOS.  Try updating BIOS

Comment: Will try BIOS update and get back, thanks.

Comment: @John BIOS updated but still the same issue.

Comment: I’ve seen this problem before. It was years ago. It had to do with some settings in the BIOS. I either had to enable or disable Legacy/CSM support and/or switch the primary graphic adapter in the UEFI firmware (I.e. your “BIOS” settings). Hopefully you have installed windows in UEFI mode and should look for disabling legacy (or CSM) mode.

Comment: Looks like it might be “enable” CSM support. https://www.gigabyte.com/md/Support/FAQ/4274

Comment: @John i've updated the Post with new findings.

Comment: @Appleoddity i've updated the Post with new findings

Comment: Enable CSM. Possibly pull the graphics card, then enable CSM and reinstall it.

Comment: @Appleoddity I'll try that in a couple of days and get back, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot tell what the problem is. Maybe the PC was in energy saving mode instead of shut down.

But you do not need the BIOS key because you can enter the BIOS using the Windows GUI. It should even be possible without logging in.

While clicking on "Restart" you have to hold down `shift` and then select Troubleshoot > Advanced options > UEFI Firmware Settings.

It's also explained on [cocosensor.com](https://www.cocosenor.com/articles/windows-10/access-uefi-bios-in-windows-10.html) and on [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/1140602/how-to-force-my-way-into-bios-uefi).

Comment: Turning off Fast Startup can slow down the startup making it easier to get into BIOS (normally) and that is why mentioned.

Comment: `Hibernation is handled by the OS and not by the BIOS` .. no, it is handled by both (except there is no BIOS in years now.. it's UEFI)..  It is ACPI mode S4 and both the firmware and operating system play a role in how it works.  I gave you +1 for pointing out how to enter the firmware settings from the windows gui.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Thank you for the hint. I removed that part.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I know UEFI is the successor of BIOS but people still use the word "BIOS". Also I am not sure about it because there is the CSM which provides a BIOS implementation. So it's more or less both BIOS + UEFI nowadays?